# Resize a tag in html

Tags: html, css

I want to have the same size for 3 containers defined as follows:

```
 <div class="workingItemContainer">
     <div id="workingItemContainer" runat="server">
         <a class="workingItem" runat="server" id="workingQuoteAnchor">
           <%=quoteNumberAnchor%>
         </a>
         <br />
         <a class="workingItem" runat="server" id="workingPOMAnchor">
           <%=pomNumberAnchor%>
         </a>
         <a class="workingItem" runat="server" id="workingProdCancelAnchor">
           <%=prodCancelNumberAnchor%>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code the code in css that implements the background and the font:

```
.workingItemContainer {
    text-align: center;
}

    .workingItemContainer div {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #ff9900;
    }
```

If I display the `workingQuoteAnchor`, it shows differently from the others.

Comment: How is that first anchor different?

Comment: @LGSon , I added a photo.

Comment: Well, as you can see, they have different sizes, at least the quoteNumberAnchor is different . I am assuming now, that is different because the titles have different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added : `max-width` in

```
.workingItemContainer div {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #ff9900;
    }
```

and solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try removing the `<br>` tag that is after the `#workingQuoteAnchor` . That is most probably creating the extra space. Also if you need any spaces do that using CSS instead of changing the DOM for such cosmetic purpose.

Comment: This resolves the extra space between the titles of the items.